# Which design patterns should we use with Selenium WebDriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Page Object Pattern is obvious. But what I can do more to build better automated test cases for web application?

Comment: It varies, but in general the better your abstractions represent what the web application actually does, the more robust your tests become.

Comment: @biziclop you're right. My goal is to gain the knowledge about different design patterns than Page Object Pattern.

Comment: Have you seen PageFactory: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/PageFactory ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I may not be able to talk about any standard pattern, but here are a few things that I consider:

1. Make good use of Test Execution frameworks. I use TestNG.
2. I create a base file which makes use of most of the TestNG annotations for Setting and Tearing up.
3. Separate your Re-usable functions and call it wherever needed. I generally add these in the base class.
4. I personally prefer keeping locators too in the base file if they are too complicated. This would help you to change the locator from one place and get reflected for all. In this case, do follow a good naming convention.
5. Use collections wherever possible.
6. You can use something like ReportNG for more user friendly reports.
7. Make more use of implicit waits and avoid using JavascriptExecutors.
8. Copy the Drivers and libraries within the project folders for better mobility and less external dependencies.
9. Adding selenium WD javadoc to your project will be of some help.
10. We also make sure we have a screenshot for failed test case by over-riding the `onTestFailure` method.
11. Rest all are simple coding basics for cleaner and easy to understand code that I believe you'll be following anyway.

Hope this was of some help. Will add more points if I'm able to recall. Also, please let me know if you need more details for any of these things.

Comment: your answer looks really helpful. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Upvoted. If no better answers appear I will accept your answer :)